# Is it good to use thread when we check in the next statement to wait for the thread completion

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have seen a code where they are starting a thread and in the next statement waiting for the thread to complete .I feel there is no use of multi threading in the below context.They can directly call the function instead of creating the thread

```
    HANDLE th = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadCall, this, 0, NULL);
    if(th != NULL)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject( th, INFINITE );                
        CloseHandle( th );
    }
```

Comment: context matters, unfortunately with 4 lines of code it's anybody's guess as to what the context is. Copy paste the full code.

Comment: I can't think of many non-test cases where I would use that, to be honest.

Comment: The only good point I can see is that hopefully the "waitForSingleObject" will not block your main thread completely, so a user might have the impression that the UI is not completely dead; but there would be plenty of other ways to achieve that.